# Composer Satis does not update package on build

Tags: php, composer-php

I have setup my own private Satis package repository which works and is able to import the packages from my Git repo.

What goes wrong is that when I update my repository on Git the new package is not updated by composer. I have seen 2 packages with he same name in composer search because I added a new tag to my latest commit but the package itself on the server where I have my package installed from my local Satis repo is not updated, so Satis does seem to have it available.

Do I need to purge and build again as I get the following on purgin my Satis repo:

```
No unreferenced archives found.
```

Comment: composer will not automatically update packages to newest versions, you have to trigger the composer update manually

Comment: Sure, but that was not the question, there was some issue on my Git repo it seems.